Didn't find class "android.media.metrics.LogSessionId" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar"
My Android application crashed while using Gson to parse network request results on Android 9. This is his crash log.
Didn't find class "android.media.metrics.LogSessionId" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
 "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.android-
ivEbB6RUoYYCAZzcU5m5oQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/user/0/com.xxx.android/app_plugins_lib, /data/app/com.xxx.android-
ivEbB6RUoYYCAZzcU5m5oQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.wisdom.android-
ivEbB6RUoYYCAZzcU5m5oQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64, /prets/lib64]]

This is my project configuration:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
android {
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.android"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' }
    }
}

version = [
            kotlin_version  : '1.9.21',
            core_ktx_version: '1.3.2',
            jetpack_version : '2.2.0',
            retrofit_version: '2.9.0'
    ]

This is the location of the crash:
public class GsonResponseBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
    @Override
    public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        String response = value.string();
        BaseResult apiResponse = gson.fromJson(response, BaseResult.class);
        try {
            if (HttpCode.REQUEST_SUCCESS.equals(apiResponse.getCode())) {
                return gson.fromJson(response, type);  // CRASH HERE
            }  else {
                throw new ResultException(apiResponse.getCode(), apiResponse.getMessage());
            }
        } finally {
            value.close();
        }
    }
}

How can I fix this crash?
